# Can't set BecomeFirstResponder in EditingDidEnd Action

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am trying to do Error Checking for a Correct Time in a UItextField. I didn't want an error to pop up while the user is typing (To give them the chance to fix it first) so I thought I would do the Check during an EditingDidEnd Action. I setup ones for Hours, Minutes and Seconds. Here is the code I tried for inHours:

```
- (IBAction)inHourEditEnd:(id)sender
{
   // Check to make sure value is between 0 & 23 Hours
   if ([[[self inHour] text] intValue] >= 0 && [[[self inHour] text] intValue] < 24) {
      [self updateDuration];
   } else {
      NSString *errorDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ hours is not a valid start time. Please enter an hour between 0 and 23", [[self inHour] text]];
      UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ivalid Hour for Start Time"
                                                                   message:errorDescription
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorMessage show];
            [_inHour becomeFirstResponder];
        }

    }
```

The alert works fine but it won't go back to the textfield (inHour) after showing the alert.
It just stays on whatever textField I tapped to cause EditingDidEnd. Searching here I found a way to make the alertView send the user back to the right textbox using this code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   //Checks For Approval
   if (buttonIndex == 0) {
      [_inHour becomeFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

But this will only work for the first box and I need to make it work with inHour, inMinute and inSeconds.

Any Suggestions how I can make this work?
Is either one of these paths in the right direction?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do your validation *after* the text field has already lost first responder status, you could add a property to your view controller to track the text field that needs to receive `becomeFirstResponder`:

```
// in your .m file, declare a class extension for "private" members
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *lastValidationFailureField;
@end

// add this to inHourEditEnd:
self.lastValidationFailureField = _inHour;

// use this property in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
[self.lastValidationFailureField becomeFirstResponder];
self.lastValidationFailureField = nil;
```

Alternatively, you could prevent the user from leaving the text field. Have your view controller implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and set all of your text fields’ `delegate` outlets to your view controller. Then implement `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == [self inHour]) {
        if ([[textField text] intValue] >= 0 && [[textField text] intValue] < 24) {
            [self updateDuration];
        } else {
            NSString *errorDescription = ...
            UIAlertView *errorMessage = ...
            [errorMessage show];
            // prevent the text field from even losing first responder status
            return NO;
        }
    }
    if (textField == [some someOtherTextFieldToValidate)] {
        ...
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I put all of the logic in a single method here for brevity, I would recommend at least some minimal refactoring of that code if you have more than a couple of text fields to validate.

You would not need your actions method such as `inHourEditEnd:` any more.

Comment: textFieldShouldEndEditing is exactly what I was looking for. Thought editingDidEnd was my only option. Thanks, works perfectly.